# Polars list of values based on intersection of different column list with another dataset

Tags: python-polars

I have a dataframe with `people` and the `food` they like:

```py
df_class = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        'people': ['alan', 'bob', 'charlie'],
        'food': [['orange', 'apple'], ['banana', 'cherry'], ['banana', 'grape']]
    }
)
print(df_class)

shape: (3, 2)
┌─────────┬──────────────────────┐
│ people  ┆ food                 │
│ ---     ┆ ---                  │
│ str     ┆ list[str]            │
╞═════════╪══════════════════════╡
│ alan    ┆ ["orange", "apple"]  │
│ bob     ┆ ["banana", "cherry"] │
│ charlie ┆ ["banana", "grape"]  │
└─────────┴──────────────────────┘
```

And, I have a data structure with `animals` and the things they like to eat:

```py
animals = [
    ('squirrel', ('acorn', 'almond')),
    ('parrot', ('cracker', 'grape', 'guava')),
    ('dog', ('chicken', 'bone')),
    ('monkey', ('banana', 'plants'))
]
```

I want to add a new column `pets` in `df_class`, such that `pets` is a list of the animals that have at least one food in common with the corresponding person:

```py
df_class.with_columns(pets=???)   # <-- not sure what to do here

shape: (3, 3)
┌─────────┬──────────────────────┬──────────────────────┐
│ people  ┆ food                 ┆ pets                 │
│ ---     ┆ ---                  ┆ ---                  │
│ str     ┆ list[str]            ┆ list[str]            │
╞═════════╪══════════════════════╪══════════════════════╡
│ alan    ┆ ["orange", "apple"]  ┆ []                   │
│ bob     ┆ ["banana", "cherry"] ┆ ["monkey"]           │
│ charlie ┆ ["banana", "grape"]  ┆ ["monkey", "parrot"] │
└─────────┴──────────────────────┴──────────────────────┘
```

- I have some flexibility in the data structure for `animals`, in case for e.g. this is easier to do with some sort of set intersection
- the order of pets is unimportant
- pets should contain unique values
- I'm looking for a single expression that would achieve the desired result, so as to fit within a larger framework of a list of expressions that perform transformations on other columns of my actual dataset

Side note:  my title seems kind of clunky and I'm open to suggestions to reword so that it's easier to find by others that might be trying to solve a similar problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a `join` on the exploded lists.

It can be kept as a "single expression" by putting it inside [`.map_batches()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.map_batches.html#polars-map-batches)

```py
df_class.with_columns(pets = 
   pl.col("food").map_batches(lambda col:
      pl.LazyFrame(col)
        .with_row_index()
        .explode("food")
        .join(
           pl.LazyFrame(animals, schema=["pets", "food"]).explode("food"),
           on = "food",
           how = "left"
        )
        .group_by("index", maintain_order=True)
        .agg(
           pl.col("pets").unique().drop_nulls()
        )
        .collect()
        .get_column("pets")
   )
)
```

```py
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────────┬──────────────────────┬──────────────────────┐
│ people  ┆ food                 ┆ pets                 │
│ ---     ┆ ---                  ┆ ---                  │
│ str     ┆ list[str]            ┆ list[str]            │
╞═════════╪══════════════════════╪══════════════════════╡
│ alan    ┆ ["orange", "apple"]  ┆ []                   │
│ bob     ┆ ["banana", "cherry"] ┆ ["monkey"]           │
│ charlie ┆ ["banana", "grape"]  ┆ ["monkey", "parrot"] │
└─────────┴──────────────────────┴──────────────────────┘
```

#### Explanation

We add a row index to the "left" frame and [explode](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.explode.html#polars.DataFrame.explode) the lists.

(The row index will allow us to rebuild the rows later on.)

```py
df_class_long = df_class.with_row_index().explode("food")

# shape: (6, 3)
# ┌───────┬─────────┬────────┐
# │ index ┆ people  ┆ food   │
# │ ---   ┆ ---     ┆ ---    │
# │ u32   ┆ str     ┆ str    │
# ╞═══════╪═════════╪════════╡
# │ 0     ┆ alan    ┆ orange │
# │ 0     ┆ alan    ┆ apple  │
# │ 1     ┆ bob     ┆ banana │
# │ 1     ┆ bob     ┆ cherry │
# │ 2     ┆ charlie ┆ banana │
# │ 2     ┆ charlie ┆ grape  │
# └───────┴─────────┴────────┘
```

```py
df_pets_long = pl.DataFrame(animals, schema=["pets", "food"]).explode("food")

# shape: (9, 2)
# ┌──────────┬─────────┐
# │ pets     ┆ food    │
# │ ---      ┆ ---     │
# │ str      ┆ str     │
# ╞══════════╪═════════╡
# │ squirrel ┆ acorn   │
# │ squirrel ┆ almond  │
# │ parrot   ┆ cracker │
# │ parrot   ┆ grape   │
# │ parrot   ┆ guava   │
# │ dog      ┆ chicken │
# │ dog      ┆ bone    │
# │ monkey   ┆ banana  │
# │ monkey   ┆ plants  │
# └──────────┴─────────┘
```

We then use a [Left Join](https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/transformations/joins/#left-join) to find the "intersections" (whilst keeping all the rows from the left side).

```py
df_class_long.join(df_pets_long, on="food", how="left")

# shape: (6, 4)
# ┌───────┬─────────┬────────┬────────┐
# │ index ┆ people  ┆ food   ┆ pets   │
# │ ---   ┆ ---     ┆ ---    ┆ ---    │
# │ u32   ┆ str     ┆ str    ┆ str    │
# ╞═══════╪═════════╪════════╪════════╡
# │ 0     ┆ alan    ┆ orange ┆ null   │
# │ 0     ┆ alan    ┆ apple  ┆ null   │
# │ 1     ┆ bob     ┆ banana ┆ monkey │
# │ 1     ┆ bob     ┆ cherry ┆ null   │
# │ 2     ┆ charlie ┆ banana ┆ monkey │
# │ 2     ┆ charlie ┆ grape  ┆ parrot │
# └───────┴─────────┴────────┴────────┘
```

We can then rebuild the "rows" with [`.group_by()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.group_by.html#polars.DataFrame.group_by)

- You stated you want [`.unique()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.unique.html#polars.Expr.unique) pets only.
- We also [drop nulls.](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.drop_nulls.html#polars.Expr.drop_nulls)

```py
(df_class_long.join(df_pets_long, on="food", how="left")
  .group_by("index", maintain_order=True) # we need to retain row order
  .agg(pl.col("pets").unique().drop_nulls())
)

# shape: (3, 2)
# ┌───────┬──────────────────────┐
# │ index ┆ pets                 │
# │ ---   ┆ ---                  │
# │ u32   ┆ list[str]            │
# ╞═══════╪══════════════════════╡
# │ 0     ┆ []                   │
# │ 1     ┆ ["monkey"]           │
# │ 2     ┆ ["monkey", "parrot"] │
# └───────┴──────────────────────┘
```

Comment: This works!  Thank you so much, I've only been working with Polars a month or so and I would never have been able to figure this out myself.  As it is, I'm still scratching my head trying to understand all the details.  It works fine for my test cases.  My actual dataset is ~ 75GB so I'm curious how this complex expression will play out at scale.

Comment: @teejay I've added an attempted explanation of what's going on. (I had also forgotten a `maintain_order=True` in the group by - oops). For larger data - you probably want to be working with LazyFrames.

Comment: @jquriuos is there anything about this approach that would prevent it from using all available cores (or rather, vCPUs on an AWS EC2 instance)?  I noticed while running some benchmarking tests on my datasets that on an 8 vCPU instance one of the vCPUs was maxed out while the others were unused.

Comment: @teejay It uses all cores on my system. While testing a larger example, I have noticed that changing `pl.col("pets").drop_nulls().unique()` to `pl.col("pets").unique().drop_nulls()` essentially halves the runtime.

Comment: The additional explanation is super helpful.  Is the only purpose of the `maintain_order` in the `group_by` to preserve the order of the original rows?  Thanks for the tip on the relative ordering of `drop_nulls()` and `unique()`, I'm also seeing a performance improvement (though not as much as halving the time) on my dataset.
I notice that with the addition of this expression my query no longer runs in streaming mode.  Is there any way to achieve the same result while continuing to run in streaming?  I already tried specifying `maintain_order=False` but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: `group_by` doesn't retain the original row order by default so the resulting `pets` column could end up misaligned without it. When you say streaming, are you using `.sink_parquet`?

Comment: By "misaligned", do you mean `people` could end up with the wrong list of `pets`?  Or simply that the `alan`, `bob` and `charlie` rows (with the correctly assigned `pets`) might end up in a different order from the original data frame (e.g. `charlie`, `alan`, `bob`)?  The latter would not be a big deal, the former would be problematic of course as it cuts to the hear of the logic I'm trying to implement.

Comment: re: streaming... after my transformation expressions, I am doing `df.collect(streaming=True).write_parquet(...)`.  I can check if streaming happening by doing df.explain(streaming=True).  If I exclude the `pets` expression everything is streaming.  If I include the `pets` expression, only `scan_parquet` is streaming, expressions are non-streaming.  I was able to revert to streaming by setting `is_elementwise=True` for `map_batches`.

Comment: ... However the documentation on this simply says "If set to true this can run in the streaming engine, but may yield incorrect results in group-by. Ensure you know what you are doing!" without explaining how it impacts the logic that is applied.

Comment: misaligned = wrong list of pets - yes. `map_batches` is not being used in a group-by context here so the doc warning should not apply.

Comment: I set `is_elementwise=True` for `map_batches`, that (along with `streaming=True` in my eventual `collect`) seems to be keeping the memory footprint steady even as I test with larger datasets.  Thank you for responding so quickly to all my follow-up questions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different solution using slightly simpler expression than [the existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78190236/2132753).

First, change the structure of your `animals` dictionary so it's easier to use with Polars:

```py
food_to_animal = {}
for animal, foods in animals:
    for food in foods:
        food_to_animal[food] = animal
```

`food_to_animal` should look like this:

(Here I'm assuming a `dict[str,str]` is usable on your real data. If you need something like a `dict[str, list[str]]` then the Polars code below would need some changes)

```
{'acorn': 'squirrel',
 'almond': 'squirrel',
 'cracker': 'parrot',
 'grape': 'parrot',
 'guava': 'parrot',
 'chicken': 'dog',
 'bone': 'dog',
 'banana': 'monkey',
 'plants': 'monkey'}
```

Now, simply use `.replace` on each of the elements of the list:

```py
df_class.with_columns(
    pets=pl.col("food").list.eval(
        pl.element().replace(food_to_animal, default=None)
    ).list.drop_nulls()
)
```

Output:

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────────┬──────────────────────┬──────────────────────┐
│ people  ┆ food                 ┆ pets                 │
│ ---     ┆ ---                  ┆ ---                  │
│ str     ┆ list[str]            ┆ list[str]            │
╞═════════╪══════════════════════╪══════════════════════╡
│ alan    ┆ ["orange", "apple"]  ┆ []                   │
│ bob     ┆ ["banana", "cherry"] ┆ ["monkey"]           │
│ charlie ┆ ["banana", "grape"]  ┆ ["monkey", "parrot"] │
└─────────┴──────────────────────┴──────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Interesting alternative.  Is there a variation that would work if a food was eaten by multiple animals?  e.g. if grape was eaten by monkey as well as by parrot?