Python-Polars: Compare Structs "row-wise"
In Python-Polars I am comparing two Pl.Struct using one of the fields of the struct as index. In other words, in the DataFrame below I am checking whether the value for id1 (i.e. 10) is in the second struct with the same value, regardless of the position:
shape: (1, 3)
┌───────────────────────────┬───────────────────────────┬───────────────┐
│ struct1                   ┆ struct2                   ┆ match_results │
│ ---                       ┆ ---                       ┆ ---           │
│ struct[2]                 ┆ struct[2]                 ┆ list[bool]    │
╞═══════════════════════════╪═══════════════════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ {["id1", "id2"],[10, 20]} ┆ {["id4", "id1"],[10, 10]} ┆ [true, false] │
└───────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────┴───────────────┘

I can achieve the above using map_elements:

def compare_structs(struct1, struct2):
    ids1, vals1 = struct1["identifiers"], struct1["values"]
    ids2, vals2 = struct2["identifiers"], struct2["values"]
    return [
        any(id1 == id2 and val1 == val2 for id2, val2 in zip(ids2, vals2))
        for id1, val1 in zip(ids1, vals1)
    ]


df.with_columns(
    pl.struct(["struct1", "struct2"])
    .map_elements(lambda s: compare_structs(s["struct1"], s["struct2"]))
    .alias("match_results")
)



But the solution is highly inefficient. Do you have any suggestion on how to improve it while keeping the expressions in a single context?

.map_batches(lambda s: s.struct.unnest()) will give you a DataFrame inside the function, meaning you can wrap frame level operations inside a single context. https://stackoverflow.com/a/78190236/ But if this is the result from the previous question it probably makes sense to show the actual starting raw data as it is likely easier to do it all in one go.

df = df.with_row_index()

df1 = df.select("struct1","index").unnest("struct1").explode(pl.exclude("index"))
df2 = df.select("struct2","index").unnest("struct2").explode(pl.exclude("index"))

df3 = (
    df1.join(df2, on=["index","field1"], how="left")
    .select(
        pl.col.index,
        result = (pl.col.field2 == pl.col.field2_right).fill_null(False)
    ).group_by("index")
    .agg(pl.all())
)

df.join(df3, on="index", how="left").drop("index")

shape: (1, 3)
┌───────────────────────────┬───────────────────────────┬───────────────┐
│ struct1                   ┆ struct2                   ┆ result        │
│ ---                       ┆ ---                       ┆ ---           │
│ struct[2]                 ┆ struct[2]                 ┆ list[bool]    │
╞═══════════════════════════╪═══════════════════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ {["id1", "id2"],[10, 20]} ┆ {["id4", "id1"],[10, 10]} ┆ [true, false] │
└───────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────┴───────────────┘

Alternatively, you can avoid last join and use concat:
df1 = df.select("struct1").unnest("struct1").with_row_index().explode(pl.exclude("index"))
df2 = df.select("struct2").unnest("struct2").with_row_index().explode(pl.exclude("index"))

df3 = (
    df1.join(df2, on=["index","field1"], how="left")
    .select(
        pl.col.index,
        result = (pl.col.field2 == pl.col.field2_right).fill_null(False)
    ).group_by("index", maintain_order=True)
    .agg(pl.all())
    .drop("index")
)

pl.concat([df,df3], how="horizontal")


